# SharePoint (2013) Designer with Multiple Front Ends not Deploying Changes to all WFEs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-farm

When I change a .aspx file using SharePoint Designer (2013), it does not seem to propagate to all front ends.  We have a WFE01, WFE02, and WFE03, and the changes only are made on the server that the SP Designer client is connected to, but not the others.  So I am guessing there is only a 1/3 chance that an end user will see the update?

Our farm was created by a third party, so I have little knowledge of how it it works.  Is the farm supposed to propagate all the changes made in SP Designer?  Or is it possible to individually open SP Designer directly on each WFE and make the same change to the .aspx file 3 times?

Comment: Just a wild guess: where exactly is the ASPX file located? On disk? Typically, when we change ASPX files, we are actually updating the database. Front Ends don't store these pages, but retreive them from the Content Database. So there is nothing to propagate. If you are updating a page that's in the Layouts folder - then it's not recommended.

Comment: Why is SP Designer connected to a WFE server? You need to provide the site URL to connect with SD, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can restart the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" service. Sometimes, using the central administration UI it does not allow to restart, so you can use the below PowerShell command:

```
$svc = Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -like "*Foundation Web*"}
$svc.Status = "Online"
$svc.Update()
```

In order to get virtual directories back run this PowerShell command

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://webAppUrl
$wa.ProvisionGlobally()
```

Source:

[Restart Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application Service. Stuck at Stopping !](https://sharepointumar.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/restart-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-web-application-service-stuck-at-stopping/)